# Local Storage error with JBoss

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jboss

I have a Web App on Firebase, the application is running on the server fine, the alert is also working fine it shows the correct user id,
but with the BrowserSim(JBoss Plugin) Emulator on Eclipse, I got these errors:

```
!JavaScript WARN: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback.
!JavaScript ERROR: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'localStorage.setItem') on line 17
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
rootRef.authWithPassword(userObject, function(error, user) {
    if(error) {
        alert(error + " " +  error.code);
        location.refresh();
    }
    if(user) {
        alert(user.uid);
        localStorage.setItem("uid", user.uid);
        location.href = "overview.html";
    }
});
```

Why does the localStorage isn´t working on the emulator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the emulator cache from Eclipse for the internal storage was full and has a bug. It works a few times fine and after this it has a bug and returns null.